# How to read JSON array with @ # tags in data using jQuery,

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
    "locenter": [
        {
            "loname": {
                "@empid": "1001",
                "#text": "FE1"
            },
            "centers": [
                {
                    "@id": "0000100001",
                    "#text": "dcgiDal"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "loname": {
                "@empid": "1002",
                "#text": "FE2"
            },
            "centers": [
                {
                    "@id": "0000300006",
                    "#text": "dcgiDah"
                },
                {
                    "@id": "0000100006",
                    "#text": "dcgiDau"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: are you having a specific problem with this? What have you tried and what makes @# so hard?

Comment: got it locenter.centers["@id"]  / locenter.centers["#text"] this is how i need to access

Comment: Philip Potter  i wanted to access @id and #text values !! got it thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you read any other JSON: `jQuery.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse`.  Simplified:

```
var o = jQuery.parseJSON('{"loname": { "@empid": "1001", "#text": "FE1" } }');
```

If you use `jQuery.ajax` with `datatype` 'json' (and possibly if you let it guess), it will do this for you.

After parsing it, you may have to use the array-like syntax to access properties.  In Firefox at least, this is only necessary for the number sign:

```
alert(o.loname['#text']);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WDB8a/1/)