# How do I extract the value of this .NET dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, dynamic, json.net

Using Json.NET I converted some xml to json then deserialized the json into a dynamic instance.

I can't seem to extract the value for this property: **#text**

Here's the immediate debug output value...

```
item.sellingStatus.currentPrice {
  "@currencyId": "AUD",
  "#text": "9.95"
} base: {
  "@currencyId": "AUD",
  "#text": "9.95"
} Type: Object
```

the xml source was this ...

```
<item>
    <sellingStatus>
        <currentPrice currencyId="AUD">5.8</currentPrice>
    </sellingStatus>
</item>
```

and Json.NET converted that into the above json ... with those crazy symbols!

How can i grab the value?

#### Update

1. [Here's the Json data](https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/9543980) which was created from the Xml

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) Converting Between JSON and XML, the `@` is for attributes and the `#` is for character data.  That explains the "crazy symbols", but doesn't exactly answer your question (hence this is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637983/how-to-read-json-array-with-tags-in-data-using-jquery Have a look at this SO thread.

Comment: @WozzeC nope -> your link is for jQuery. So those clues didn't work for me :(

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, what do you get if you drag the object you want to access into the Visual Studio watch window? Does it expand into a full definition you can grab? Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: @Baldrick - nope, no misunderstanding at all. u got it. VS throws some weird error when i drill down to it. I'm on a notebook with no printscrn so i can't grab a screenie :( If i use the 'on-screen-keyboard', then when i move the mouse off the value, it dissapears... i'll try and grab a screen still. keyboard, where's my keyboard....

Comment: Can you show how the Json is presented after you convert it from XML to JSon?

Comment: oh! great idea @WozzeC - here's the full gist: https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/9543980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded Json.Net and performed the deserialization process for .NET4.0. This code works for me:

```
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput);
foreach (var item in root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.item)
{
    string CurrencyID = item.sellingStatus.currentPrice["@currencyId"].Value;
    double Amount = double.Parse(item.sellingStatus.currentPrice["#text"].Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

So from what I can tell it seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: This thing is very case sensitive, just so you know :)

Comment: Oh - i also wasn't too sure that the syntax was `[".."]` ..  which was the 2nd gotcha for me.

Comment: Such pain, very annoyance! Glad I could help :)